# How to show an image when clicked?

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

I have some images (they are the same for now but will be different later on) and I want one to fill up the screen when I click it.

img_back is the background for when the large image is displayed.
gallery_document is the whole page so that the img_back can be shown.

The two functions are (supposed to):

1. Find the image which was clicked.
2. Display it large over the img_back.

```js
function clicked(img_src) {
  return img_src;
}
function imgDisplay() {
    $('.img_back').show();
    $('.gallery_document').hide();
    document.getElementByClass('image_large').src = clicked(img_src);
}
```

```css
 body {
  border-top:0px;
  margin-top:0px;
  margin-right:0px;
  margin-bottom:0px;
  margin-left:0px;
}
.container-fluid {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #fff;
}
.no-gutter > [class*='col-'] {
    padding-right:0;
    padding-left:0;
}
.img_back {
  background-color: #000000;
  display: none;
  opacity: 0.8;
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
.gallery_img {
    width: 90%;
    display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
  margin-bottom: 10%;
  margin-top: 10%;
}
.img_div {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}
.gallery_img:hover {
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class = "row no-gutter img_back">
  <div class = "image_large_div">
    <img class = "image_large"/>
  </div>

  <div class = "gallery_document">
    <div class = "row no-gutter gallery_imgs">
      <div class = "col-xs-3 img_div">
        <img class = "gallery_img" id = "img_1" onclick = "clicked(this.src) ; imgDisplay()" src = "https://avante.biz/wp-content/uploads/1280x720-Wallpapers/1280x720-Wallpapers-032.jpg"/>
      </div>
      <div class = "col-xs-3 img_div">
        <img class = "gallery_img" id = "img_2" onclick = "clicked(this.src) ; imgDisplay()" src = "https://avante.biz/wp-content/uploads/1280x720-Wallpapers/1280x720-Wallpapers-032.jpg"/>
      </div>
      <div class = "col-xs-3 img_div">
        <img class = "gallery_img" id = "img_3" onclick = "clicked(this.src) ; imgDisplay()" src = "https://avante.biz/wp-content/uploads/1280x720-Wallpapers/1280x720-Wallpapers-032.jpg"/>
      </div>
      <div class = "col-xs-3 img_div">
        <img class = "gallery_img" id = "img_4" onclick = "clicked(this.src) ; imgDisplay()" src = "https://avante.biz/wp-content/uploads/1280x720-Wallpapers/1280x720-Wallpapers-032.jpg"/>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class = "row no-gutter gallery_imgs">
      <div class = "col-xs-3 img_div">
        <img class = "gallery_img" id = "img_5" onclick = "clicked(this.src) ; imgDisplay()" src = "https://avante.biz/wp-content/uploads/1280x720-Wallpapers/1280x720-Wallpapers-032.jpg"/>
      </div>
      <div class = "col-xs-3 img_div">
        <img class = "gallery_img" id = "img_6" onclick = "clicked(this.src) ; imgDisplay()" src = "https://avante.biz/wp-content/uploads/1280x720-Wallpapers/1280x720-Wallpapers-032.jpg"/>
      </div>
      <div class = "col-xs-3 img_div">
        <img class = "gallery_img" id = "img_7" onclick = "clicked(this.src) ; imgDisplay()" src = "https://avante.biz/wp-content/uploads/1280x720-Wallpapers/1280x720-Wallpapers-032.jpg"/>
      </div>
      <div class = "col-xs-3 img_div">
        <img class = "gallery_img" id = "img_8" onclick = "clicked(this.src) ; imgDisplay()" src = "https://avante.biz/wp-content/uploads/1280x720-Wallpapers/1280x720-Wallpapers-032.jpg"/>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not fully sure this is the functionality you were going for, I hope it matches your expectations. A couple of changes I've made:

- Replaced the single image by different cat pictures as everything is better with cats (and with different images it is easier to see what is happening).
- Moved the clicked handlers out of the HTML `onclick` attributes and into JS. Instead of having to add this on every HTML element, I only need a single click handler for the same functionality.
- Changed the HTML structure a bit to move the larger preview image to its own container. I could not figure out how your solution was supposed to work.
- For the large preview image I used the `background-image` CSS property, I find it easier to work with when I want the image to fill out an element while keeping its aspect ratio.
- Replaced the jQuery calls with native JS calls, there was nothing you were doing that required the usage of jQuery.

I've added some comments in the code to explain what is going on, I hope it is clear this way.

```js
/**
 * Handles the click event on the large preview image. Whenever it is clicked,
 * the element should be hidden again so the thumbnails become visible again.
 */
function onPreviewImageClicked(event) {
  // Hide the preview image by setting the "hidden" CSS class on it.
  previewImage.classList.add('hidden');
  // Show the thumbnails again by removing the "hidden" CSS class.
  thumbnailGallery.classList.remove('hidden');
}

/**
 * Handles all the clicks on the elements inside the thumbnail gallery.
 */
function onThumbnailClicked(event) {
  // Check if the clicked element has the "gallery_img" class, when it doesn't just
  // ignore the click.
  if (!event.target.classList.contains('gallery_img')) {
    return;
  }
  
  // Hide the thumbnails by setting the "hidden" class on the element.
  thumbnailGallery.classList.add('hidden');
  // Set the backgroundImage CSS property on the preview element to the same
  // src as the clicked image.
  previewImage.style.backgroundImage = `url(${event.target.src})`;
  // Make the preview image visible by removing the "hidden" class from it.
  previewImage.classList.remove('hidden');
}


const
  // Get the first, and in this case only, element with the class "image_preview".
  previewImage = document.querySelector('.image_preview'),
  thumbnailGallery = document.querySelector('.gallery_document');

// Attach an event handler to handle clicks on the element.
previewImage.addEventListener('click', onPreviewImageClicked);

// Attach an event handler to the thumbnail gallery.
thumbnailGallery.addEventListener('click', onThumbnailClicked);
```

```css
body {
  border-top:0px;
  margin-top:0px;
  margin-right:0px;
  margin-bottom:0px;
  margin-left:0px;
}
.container-fluid {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #fff;
}
.no-gutter > [class*='col-'] {
    padding-right:0;
    padding-left:0;
}
.img_back {
  background-color: #000000;
  opacity: 0.8;
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
.gallery_img {
    width: 90%;
    display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
  margin-bottom: 10%;
  margin-top: 10%;
}
.img_div {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}
.gallery_img:hover {
  cursor:pointer;
}

.col-xs-3 {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
}

.image_preview {
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  height: 100vh;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  z-index: 4;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class = "row no-gutter img_back">

  <div class = "gallery_document">
    <div class = "row no-gutter gallery_imgs">
      <div class = "col-xs-3 img_div">
        <img class = "gallery_img" id = "img_1"  src = "http://lorempixel.com/1280/720/cats/1"/>
      </div>
      <div class = "col-xs-3 img_div">
        <img class = "gallery_img" id = "img_2"  src = "http://lorempixel.com/1280/720/cats/2"/>
      </div>
      <div class = "col-xs-3 img_div">
        <img class = "gallery_img" id = "img_3"  src = "http://lorempixel.com/1280/720/cats/3"/>
      </div>
      <div class = "col-xs-3 img_div">
        <img class = "gallery_img" id = "img_4"  src = "http://lorempixel.com/1280/720/cats/4"/>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class = "row no-gutter gallery_imgs">
      <div class = "col-xs-3 img_div">
        <img class = "gallery_img" id = "img_5"  src = "http://lorempixel.com/1280/720/cats/5"/>
      </div>
      <div class = "col-xs-3 img_div">
        <img class = "gallery_img" id = "img_6"  src = "http://lorempixel.com/1280/720/cats/6"/>
      </div>
      <div class = "col-xs-3 img_div">
        <img class = "gallery_img" id = "img_7"  src = "http://lorempixel.com/1280/720/cats/7"/>
      </div>
      <div class = "col-xs-3 img_div">
        <img class = "gallery_img" id = "img_8"  src = "http://lorempixel.com/1280/720/cats/8"/>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="image_preview hidden"></div>
```

Comment: I've updated the answer with changes I've made and cleaned up the code a bit. I hope this is what you were looking for.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Really appreciate it.

Comment: Thanks, that is good to hear. When this is the info you were looking for, can you mark it as the accepted answer?

Comment: Will do. I am integrating it into the website now. Will get back to u soon

Comment: I have tried the code in my website and in JSfiddle but neither seem to work. The html and css are fine but my JS knowledge is a bit on the weak side and i can't seem to get it to work. Thanks in advance

Comment: Sorry to hear. What problem are you running into?

Comment: I checked in another program and it says that the line "previewImage.addEventListener('click', onPreviewImageClicked);" is null.(Second to last line of code). Thanks

Comment: Still saying the addEventListeners are null. It will not work on any of my web browsers and I cannot see why they are coming back as null.

Comment: The problem was that the JS was loading before the page and so the elements were not yet available to be called. I fixed it with a window onload. Do you mind if I slightly modify your answer?

Comment: I don't think the answer needs to be modified, it works properly and it is the situation as you laid it out in your question. I'm really glad that you fixed on your actual site, sounds like you did some good debugging.

Comment: Sounds ok. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a javascript function which gets the id of the image and onclick sets the width and height of that id to 70-80% or as per your requirement.

Comment: Will try it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you don't really NEED JavaScript for this, but it makes it more stable. Since I do not know JavaScript, I manipulate HTML and CSS to simulate javascript functions.

In CSS, if you use something like:

```
    img {
        visability: hidden;
    }
    img.HOVER {
        img-size: 100%;
    }
```

I hope this helped!

(EDIT: Ignore this plz.... someone put better solution)

Comment: Will try it. Thanks

Comment: You are very welcome! If you have any further problems for that attempt, please email me at minecraftnerd736@gmail.com, or just reply to this comment.